# How to send multiple hex data payload in the jmeter tcp sampler?

Tags: node.js, tcp, jmeter, payload, jmeter-3.2

How to send multiple hex data payload in the jmeter tcp sampler in the same socket? The EOL Byte is not ending the payload and sending the two payloads as one payload. I want the two payloads to go one after another in the same connection established.

Comment: have yo checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585628/jmeter-tcp-sampler-how-to-reuse-connection-between-threads?

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario I believe it will be much easier to use [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler with `Keep-alive connection` box checked, this way you will be able to send as many "payloads" (whatever it is ) as you need using a single socket connection.

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter HTTP Raw Request Sampler]

---

Be aware that any JMeter limitation can be worked around using scripting so you should be able to implement whatever functionality you need using J[SR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), check out [Groovy Sockets example](http://programmingitch.blogspot.com/2010/04/groovy-sockets-example.html) for reference.